Regex to match first two numbers in a string?
I have a string of this format:
words 9999 words words words 1234 words words words words 3333...

The words and numbers are unknown. Additionally, a the number of words and numbers and their order is unknown. So this is also fine:
words words words 9999 words words words words words words 1234 words 9934 4945 6945...

I want to match only the first two numbers in the string. What regex can do this?
Edit: I cannot just select the first two numbers, as there can be a tremendous amount, and it is a huge waste of time to match all of them. In particular, my testing string has over 16,000 numbers.

Just look for numbers with \d+ and select the first two matches? What is the problem?

@trincot I'll edit this into the main question, but there can be a tremendous amount of numbers. My testing string has over 16,000, for example.

I'm not suggesting that you should collect all matches. Just the first two. For instance, use regex_iterator. There is example code in the docs.

You can use \d+ twice to achieve this.


const string = "words 9999 words words words 1234 words words words words 3333";
const pattern = /^\D*(\d+)\D*(\d+)/;
const match = string.match(pattern);

if (match) {
    const firstNumber = match[1];
    const secondNumber = match[2];
    console.log(firstNumber, secondNumber);
}




FWIW, for text with only one number (e.g. "text 1234"), it gives two groups "123" and "4".

@HaoWu Excellent observation, so we could prepend a word boundary \b to the second \d+ as long as nothing like e.g. a123 occurs where the number needs to be extracted.

Just one idea, the code has not been optimized


  var pattern = /[0-9]+/
  const str = 'words words words 9999 words words words words words words 1234 words 9934 4945 6945';
  const words = str.split(' ');
  const match = str.match(pattern)
  words.splice(words.indexOf(match[0]), 1)
  const str2 = words.join(' ')
  const match2 = str2.match(pattern)
  console.log(match)
  console.log(match2)




As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
